# Spring Boot -- Don't see a jsp page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When I deploy **jar** file at the localhost, all fine. But at the server machine, after deploying, when I go to the page, I get error at the server:

[image: 404 page]
Why Spring don't see *jsp* file?

Comment: Is that a runnable jar, with embedded Tomcat?

Comment: yes, spring-boot-starter-tomcat and tomcat-embed-jasper

Comment: Posting full stack trace will help grasp the problem!

Comment: do you have a `context path` set in your application?